# How to update multiple fields(array field and normal field) in a single document of mongo db at a time using JAVA?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I want to update request fields only in an array using java.This is my existing document in mongo db:

```
{
    "_id": "6691e5068dwe335w42cb0a699650f",
    "Opportunity_Owner": "Self",
    "Account_Name": "IC",
    "Lead_Source": "Callbox",
    "Opportunity_Name": "name1 ",
    "Stage": "Proposal",
    "Stage_Status": "A",
    "1555570551211": [],
    "1555556165153": [],
    "1555556059584": [{
            "id": "1557389940585",
            "Notes": "Note 1"
        },
        {
            "id": "1557389945398",
            "Notes": "Hi Bobby "
        },
        {
            "id": "1557389978181",
            "Notes": "Spoken to Bobby."
        },
        {
            "id": "1557389990159",
            "Notes": "plan to call on 29/Apr"
        }
    ],

    "createdBy": "2c18b8dbb7d74a41a66f53a90117480a",
    "createdDate": "1562911250917"
}
```

Request payload:

```
{
 "_id" : "6691e5068dwe335w42cb0a699650f",
 "Stage_Status" : "I",
 "1555556059584" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "1557389940585",
            "Notes" : "updated note 123"
        }
     ]
}
```

I am trying to update  "Stage_Status" and "1555556059584.Notes"  at a time  using $set.I am able to update "Stage_Status" but "1555556059584" array is going to reset with what i have updated with last one.

expected output:

```
 {
        "_id" : "6691e5068dwe335w42cb0a699650f",
        "Opportunity_Owner" : "Self",
        "Account_Name" : "IC",
        "Lead_Source" : "Callbox",
        "Opportunity_Name" : "name1 ",
        "Stage" : "Proposal",
        "Stage_Status" : "I",
        "1555570551211" : [],
        "1555556165153" : [],
        "1555556059584" : [ 
            {
                "id" : "1557389940585",
                "Notes" : "updated note 123"
            }, 
            {
                "id" : "1557389945398",
               "Notes" : "Hi Bobby "
            }, 
            {
                "id" : "1557389978181",
                "Notes" : "Spoken to Bobby."
            }, 
            {
                "id" : "1557389990159",
                "Notes" : "plan to call on 29/Apr"
            }
        ],

        "createdBy" : "2c18b8dbb7d74a41a66f53a90117480a",
        "createdDate" : "1562911250917"
    }
```

can any one please help me to figure it out in java.

Answer (score 0):

I guess  you  wanted to  update `Stage_Status` and `1555556059584.Notes`   at Once .
here is a demo about it

```
> db.student.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d2c09ea8ed60ae70d3dd76b"), "name" : "bigbang", "courses" : [ { "name" : "en", "classRoom" : "9001" }, { "name" : "math", "classRoom" : "1001" } ] }
> db.student.update({name:'bigbang','courses.name':'en'},{ $set: {'courses.$.classRoom':'1009',name :"course"} })
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
> db.student.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d2c09ea8ed60ae70d3dd76b"), "name" : "course", "courses" : [ { "name" : "en", "classRoom" : "1009" }, { "name" : "math", "classRoom" : "1001" } ] }
```

the java demo  is like  this

```
collection.updateOne(and(eq("Stage_Status","A"),eq("1555556059584.id","1557389940585")),new Document("$set" ,new Document("Stage_Status","YOUR_NEW_VALUE").append("1555556059584.$.Notes","YOUR_NEW_VALUE")));
```

you must set the `1555556059584.id` to  let the diver know  which  element  to be update .